# URL validation takes too long

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program that queries a database, then takes all the URLs from the table and checks if the links work. I'm using the code below for validation.

```java
static boolean urlvalid(String theurl) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(theurl);
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
    Int statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
}
```

The issue is that this takes very long to run. It can check about 70 links per minute. How can I do this faster?

Comment: Do you actually need to check that the pages resolve, or just that the links are in a valid format? Could just use a regex to check the URL format if that's all you need, which would be a lot faster. If you really need the status code, you could look into the [threads API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) to run more requests at the same time

Comment: Use more than one thread?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma Yeah i need the status code. Im new to this, is it normal for that to take a long time?

Comment: Yes, it is normal for that to take a while @ChrisLalu, because essentially it has actually go to the webpage and wait for the server to send back a response -- in much the same way that if you go to a website in your web browser you have to wait for it to load. Additionally, because you're doing just inline, you have to wait for it to finish before it can move on to the next one. If you used threads, you could start the requests for all your urls at once, and load them all at the same time, which would be significantly faster

Comment: @Toastrackenigma okay I appreciate you help!